# Internet connection Drops during an SVN commit

Tags: svn, commit

During a large commit to a remote SVN repository, if the internet connection drops - will I have to start the commit again? OR will it "continue" where it left off ?

Thanks

Ojo

Answer (score 1):

A Subversion commit is an atomic transaction.

Either everything is committed or nothing is committed.

You would have to start the commit again.