# svn commit operation error

Tags: svn, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet connection Drops during an SVN commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854964/internet-connection-drops-during-an-svn-commit)

I changed a code on my local machine and want to commit it to the SVN server. If during commit operation there will occur an error then the code will not be commited at all or the code until the error will be commited?

Comment: So anybody can help? I need an answer

Answer (score 1):

No, if there's an error during a commit, nothing in that commit operation will be sent to the server. So if you try to commit 5 files and there's an error after file #2, none of the 5 files will be committed.